# Is there a good approximation for this?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, approximation

What is a good approximation for $\dfrac{k!}{\binom{k^2}{k}}$ as a function of $k$?

Is there a $k_0\in\Bbb N$ such that for all $k\gt k_0$, $$\frac{c}{2^{dk}}\gg\frac{k!}{\binom{k^2}{k}}\gg\frac{c}{2^{dk(\log_2 k)^{1+a}}}$$ with some fixed $c,d>0$ at every $a>0$?

Do we also have $$\frac{c}{2^{dk}}\gg\sum_{i=2}^{k}{\dfrac{(k+1)!}{{i(k+1-i)!\binom{k^2}{i}}}}\gg\frac{c}{2^{dk(\log_2 k)^{1+a}}}$$ with some fixed $c,d>0$ at every $a>0$?

Comment: Have you tried Stirling's approximation? May be too inexact though...

Comment: Yes but you have multiple appearances of factorials in your problem.. Repeated use of Stirling would work pretty well for $k>5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using almost the same approach as Ross Millikan used $$A=\frac{k!}{\binom{k^2}{k}}=\frac {(k!)^2(k^2-k)!}{(k^2)!}$$ $$\log(A)=2\log(k!)+\log\big((k^2-k)!\big)-\log\big((k^2)!\big)$$ I used Stirling expansion $$\log(n!)=n (\log (n)-1)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (2 \pi )+\log(n)
   \right)+\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{1}{360
   n^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{7/2}\right)$$ Replacing and expanding again as a series for large values of $k$, I arrived to $$\log(A)=-2 k+\left(\frac{1}{2}+\log (2k\pi )\right)-\frac{1}{6 k}-\frac{1}{6 k^2}-\frac{7}{180
   k^3}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^4\right)$$

For $n=10$ the exact result is $\approx 2.096323009\times 10^{-7}$ while the approximation leads to $\approx 2.096324531\times 10^{-7}$.

For $n=20$ the exact result is $\approx 8.725204600\times 10^{-16}$ while the approximation leads to $\approx 8.725205028\times 10^{-16}$.

**Edit**

As a very first approximation, we should then have $$A=\frac{k!}{\binom{k^2}{k}} \approx 2k \pi\,e^{-2k+\frac 12}$$

Comment: I like this answer.

Comment: Could you try this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374149/is-there-a-reasonable-approximation-for-this as well?

Comment: You are missing $k\ln k$ term right?

Comment: @Turbo. Sorry, I had a small error in my very last approximation. I hope it is correct now.

Comment: That is fine. Other question is what I am most interested in.

Answer (score 2):

First, expand the binomial into factorials.  $$\frac{k!}{\binom{k^2}{k}}=\frac {(k!)^2(k^2-k)!}{(k^2)!}$$  Then use Stirling-I will leave incorporating the $\sqrt{2 \pi n}$ to you-it will be small.
$$\frac{k!}{\binom{k^2}{k}}=\frac {(k!)^2(k^2-k)!}{(k^2)!}\\ \approx \frac{k^{2k}(k^2-k)^{(k^2-k)}e^{(k^2)}}{(k^2)^{(k^2)}e^{(2k+k^2-k)}}\\=\frac {(k^2-k)^{(k^2-k)}}{k^{2k^2-k}e^k}\\=\frac{(k^2)^{(k^2-k)}(1-\frac 1k)^{(k^2-k)}}{k^{2k^2-k}e^k}\\ =\frac {(1-\frac 1k)^{(k^2-k)}}{k^{k}e^k}$$Can you argue that the numerator is $e^{-k}$ for large $k$?

Comment: That is a better approximation than I suggested.  I should have said less than, and yours is much less.

Comment: I saw your edit, but I do not think it is correct.  Unfortunately, the edit screen does not render the MathJax, so I am not sure.  It would be better to show it as a comment.  You are adding two lines $\approx\frac{1}{ek^k}\approx e^{-k\ln k}$ but neither is correct.

Comment: No.  Since the base is less than one, raising it to a high power (as $k \to \infty$) makes it small. Your expression makes it large.  I think $(1-1/k)^{k^2-k} \approx e^{1-k}$ but am not sure.

Comment: $(1-1/k)^k\approx\frac{1}e\implies(1-1/k)^{k^2-k}\approx\frac{1}{ e^{k-1}}\implies\frac{(1-1/k)^{k^2-k}}{e^k}\approx\frac{1}{ e^{2k-1}}\implies\frac{(1- \frac{1}k)^{k^2-k}}{k^ke^k} \approx e^{-k\ln k}$?

Comment: You have a sign error in the first. $(1+1/k)^k \approx e$, so $(1-1/k)^k \approx 1/e$  That justifies $(1-1/k)^{k^2-k} \approx (1/e)^{k-1} = e^{1-k}$

Comment: ok please check modification.

Comment: I still think it would be better to comment on how I should improve my post.  The proposed edit screen does not render the MathJax, so is very hard to read.  Your second $\approx$ suppresses the $e^{-(2k-1)}$ so should be $\gg$ already.

Comment: I think your suggestion is right. In end you can prove what I need.

Comment: @RossMillikan. I don't know if and where I did something wrong but our results do not seem to match.